# Secure React App and .net 6 apis with Keycloack

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, keycloak, single-sign-on, microsoft-entra-id

I have a react frontend and a .net core web api project. I'm trying to implement authentication on these with Keycloak. I'm a bit confuse about how to connect the frontend the backend in context of keycloak and how authentication will took place in this case.
I am trying to achieve this:

- user should be able to login with username and password
- microsoft entra's user should be able to login with their tenant ids
- single sign on
  It would be very helpful if you help me in achieving this.